# Is it possible to select by id in Angulars <ng-content>?

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm playing around with Angular's (version 7) content projection. As far as I know, it's possible to select by attribute, class, and tag with the `select` attribute of `<ng-content>`.

I've also tried to select by id:

```html
<ng-content select="#myID"></ng-content>
```

From:

```html
<mycomponent>
   <div id="myid">
        Test
   </div>
</mycomponent>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Why does the selection of IDs not work?

Comment: for me is very exotic to use `<div id=...>` in angular template - can you explain why you wanna use it?

Comment: I got asked this by someone. Why is it uncommon in Angular to do this? I expected that I can use some kind of CSS selector within the select.

Comment: usually you should not use any selector to get html element in your typescript code, but OPPOSITE - usually inside your html template you use your typescript objects by using directives like *ngIf, *ngFor,, (click)="someFunction(xx)" [(ngModule)]...

Comment: so usually trying to get some html-nodes inside .ts file is wrong approach to angular... The right approach is to use javascript (typescript) object inside template (not template elements inside javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't give a reason why you can't target an ID using the syntax like `#myID`, but you are able to target attributes on DOM nodes using a syntax like `[attribute=value]` (like you are able to in CSS selectors). Using this, you can then target for a specific ID attribute. In your case you would want to use the following:

```html
<ng-content select="[id=myID]"></ng-content>
```